# Rounding spreadsheet values to nearest 0.0 / 0.5 and plotting on the graph

Tags: graph, google-sheets, rounding

I have following spreadsheet data:

[image: Sample data]

At the moment I am unable to figure out how to group it into following graph:

x-axis: sentiment (lowest to highest)
y-axis: outcome of sentiment group (lowest to highest)

To explain this graph a bit more, I need first to group all sentiment entries into `0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4 ...` each, as you can see from the data a lot of these need to be rounded up for this.

Secondly each sentiment has correlated outcome i.e. first row would be in group 3 for sentiment (x-axis) and have added 1 in y-axis as outcome, assume there are ten different sentiments in this group `3` for sentiment and each of these has either value of 1 or -1, this needs to be calculated together and group of sentiment 3 can have outcome (y-axis) as 2 for example, or anything else, it can even be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Rounding to nearest half-integer

```
 =round(B2 * 2) / 2
```

or as an arrayformula,

```
 =arrayformula(round(B2:B * 2) / 2)
```

This will have to be in its own column, say column E.

#### Grouping and adding

Then you want to total the numbers in column D for each category indicated by column E.

```
=query(D:E, "select E, sum(D) group by E order by E asc", 1)
```

Here "1" means there is one header row in the referenced range. For more, see [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: This worked really good, I was trying to edit Groping and adding query in a way that it allows 2 Outcome columns i.e Have column D and (for sake of example) identical column H and use these 2 columns against values in column E?